# Incorrect timing in delay is observed

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, timer, task, esp-idf

The below code is to generate a single line signal with two different timings, doing good if we give more than 10ms in vTaskDelay(), i.e getting perfect delay is observed but if we give lesser than 10ms the perfect signal is not observed. Please help me in this regard.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "esp_timer.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "esp_err.h"
#include "sdkconfig.h"
#include "driver/timer.h"

#define GPIO_OUTPUT_IO 2
#define TIMER_GROUP 0
#define TIMER_INDEX 0

uint64_t task_counter_value;
void turn_off(void *pvParameters);
void turn_on(void *pvParameters);

void turn_on(void *pvParameters)
{
gpio_set_level(GPIO_OUTPUT_IO, 1);
vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(30));
xTaskCreate(&turn_off, "turn_off", 2048, NULL, 10, NULL);
vTaskDelete(NULL);
}

void turn_off(void *pvParameters)
{
gpio_set_level(GPIO_OUTPUT_IO, 0);
vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(8));
xTaskCreate(&turn_on, "turn_on", 2048, NULL, 10, NULL);
vTaskDelete(NULL);
}

void app_main(void)
{
timer_config_t config;
config.alarm_en = false;
config.auto_reload = true;
config.counter_dir = TIMER_COUNT_UP;
config.intr_type = TIMER_INTR_LEVEL;
config.counter_en = TIMER_PAUSE;
config.divider = 80;

gpio_config_t io_conf;
io_conf.intr_type = GPIO_INTR_DISABLE;
io_conf.mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT;
io_conf.pin_bit_mask = (1ULL << GPIO_OUTPUT_IO);
io_conf.pull_down_en = 0;
io_conf.pull_up_en = 0;
gpio_config(&io_conf);

 timer_init(TIMER_GROUP, TIMER_INDEX, &config);
 xTaskCreate(&turn_on, "turn_on", 2048, NULL, 10, NULL);

 while (true)
{
  vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
}
}
```

Comment: There is a granularity associated with most, (all?) OS delays and this shows up more as the interval shortens.  'Perfect' is not achievable without going back to the definition, ie, a caesium clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is much better to use a time control peripheral here, and not to rely on task scheduler tick timer.
I mean, for example on ESP32 target you can use LEDC peripheral, and by hardware you will easily get frequencies in the order you need. I thinkyou need 50% duty cycle. LEDC is a PWM hardware controller. I didn´t use that but I think you can configure it for a 50% duty cycle.
Here you have more information, and of course you have sample code from Espresif.

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/ledc.html

Hope this helps you.